# Apache2: Invalid command 'LockFile'

Tags: debian, apache2

My Apache2 will not work, and when I try to run `apache2 --version` or any other apache command, it errors out with the following message:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 89 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid command 'LockFile', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

my `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` (without the *endless* comments) looks like the following:

```
LockFile ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}/accept.lock
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5

<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}                                                                                                               Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
AccessFileName .htaccess

<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</Files>

DefaultType None
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
Include mods-enabled/*.load
Include mods-enabled/*.conf
Include ports.conf
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
Include conf.d/
Include sites-enabled/
<FilesMatch \.php$>
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the [httpd 2.4 upgrading document](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#run-time). Among the several changes are the removal of `LockFile` directive:

> Directives AcceptMutex, LockFile, RewriteLock, SSLMutex,
>   SSLStaplingMutex, and WatchdogMutexPath have been replaced with a
>   single [Mutex](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex) directive. You will need to evaluate any use of
>   these removed directives in your 2.2 configuration to determine if
>   they can just be deleted or will need to be replaced using Mutex.